# Searching a string for a specified word

Tags: java, string, contains

I want to check whether the particular word entered is in the string or not. I used the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        s1 = s.next();
        String s2 = "this is an accomplishment";
        if (s2.contains(s1)) {
            System.out.println("you have done it");

        } else
            System.out.println("try another word");
    }
}
```

If I enter the word “com” I get the result

> you have done it

but "com" is actually only part of the word “accomplishment”. I want the result in this case to be

> try another word

because `s2` does not contain the complete word “com”. I also tried `indexOf()`, but that also gives the same result. In what way should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

The best regex approach is probably

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(s1) + "\\b");
if (p.matcher(s2).find()) { ... }
```

It handles word boundaries and escaping. Just be aware that compiling a Pattern isn't free.

Answer (score 1):

[Read up on the API for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

In particular, notice what contains() does. It matches if the sequence is present in the String.  It cannot distinguish the separate words in that String. As long as 'com' appears anywhere in that string, contains() returns true. You're expecting it to match whole words only, which contains() does not do.

What you can do is use a regular expression to match if a given string appears surrounded by whitespace or punctuation.  Try the Java tutorial on [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

Or, more simply, you can split your string apart along whitespace. The String method split() or another Scanner can easily do that. That'll provide you with individual words, called "tokens" by the Scanner class, as instances of the String class. After that, instead using contains(), use equals(). Regular Expressions can do this too, but they're more exhausting to learn at first (but entirely worth it).

Answer (score 0):

In place of `if(s2.contains(s1))`, use this code:

```
if(Pattern.compile("\\b" + s1 + "\\b").matcher(s2).find())
```

Make sure to `import java.util.regex.Pattern;`

It will search for an entire word in `s2` that matches `s1`. For more information, see these pages:

- [Pattern.compile(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) — Compiles a *regex*.
- [pattern.matcher(CharSequence cs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) — Gets a `Matcher` to search for the regex inside the specified string.
- [matcher.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) — Returns true if a match was found.

Alternatively, you can use

```
if(s2.matches(".*\\b" + s1 + "\\b.*"))
```